# Custom chat page with deployment API

Tags: javascript, liveagent

I'm using deployment API to open chat window. I have created custom apex page for the chat. How can I tell deployment API to use that custom page instead of default one?

Example code:

```
liveagent.init(endpoint, deployment, org);
liveagent.startChat(button, agent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set this up at the button level.

Setup > Customize > Live Agent > Chat Buttons > Edit > Custom Chat Window

Comment: Any ideaa why the custom chat page works only if do NOT specify agent ID? For example `liveagent.startChat(button);` launches chat with custom page, but `liveagent.startChat(button, agent);` launches chat with default page.

Comment: @What version of API are you using? It might be that your page is using an API version that does not support that signature.

Comment: hmm, now that you mentioned... page API version was 32 but the deployment script was 34. However I have changed page API version to 34 but it didn't do anything. I still get default chat window if I add agent id with a call to `live agent.startChat()`. Is there any debug console for this thing? Or is this pure guessing?

Comment: Seems like I'm not the only one having this issue: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DGD9AAO

Comment: You should open a case with support. It seems like a bug.

Comment: I already did, however salesforce does not want users to post developer support requests via support channel. They force us to use forums :(